# Accessing CSV files on host from .NET Core App in Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I am having a trouble to access CSV files on host from [ASP.NET Core Web API app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) running on docker container. The Web app works in Release mode according to the `Dockerfile` in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Here is my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

```
aspnetapp
|- MyApp
|  |- MyApp.csproj
|- Dockerfile
|- data
|  |- user_input.csv (I want to access here from .NET App on docker)
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  aspnetapp:
    image: aspnetapp-img
    build: ./aspnetapp
    container_name: aspnetapp-ctr
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "server=mysql; uid=root; pwd=P@ssw0rd!; database=mydb;"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql-img
    ...
```

(MyApp also uses mysql on docker, but I've omitted this part because it's not relevant to this question)

To access CSV files on host (`user_input.csv`) from MyApp container, I assume that I should mount `aspnetapp/data` to somewhere on `aspnetapp-img`. If the CSV file changes by user while running the container, the app should access the new file, so I need to mount it instead of `COPY` in Dockerfile.

Here's where my question arose.

1. Where do I mount on the docker container?
2. How to access the file from controller?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FileController : ControllerBase
{
  public IActionResult AccessCsvFile()
  {
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "user_input.csv");
    ...
```

Can I access the csv file from the controller in this way?

Comment: If it was me I'd have put the csv in say an azure Blob and got it from there, then you don't have to worry about file systems.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Actually, I'm a university student and I'm building this system as an internal system in my lab. So I dont' have the authority or money to use an external service... One possible solution is to upload files from the client (React), but if the number of files is large, I don't think it's a very good idea...

Comment: Shrugs, You can get a free account, won't cost you anything for one blob. Architecturally it has many advantages and it removes the file system from the equation.

Comment: Azure has lot of free optoins for students. Being a student is a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options:

1. Command line

```
docker run -v <relative/absolute path/data/user_input.csv>:/data/input.csv
```

2. Docker-compose

```
   volumes:
      - <relative/absolute path/data/user_input.csv>:/data/input.csv
```

more here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/#preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created

If you want to use Azure: https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver

And other plugins: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/